# Download property for link?

Tags: javascript

There is a following code:

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
```

What is property `download`, how does it work?

Comment: Please use documentation of HTML first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: I got you, but I have tried to use it like:   <li><a href="https://example.com" download>Website</a></li>

Comment: @OPV That page also says: "*download only works for same-origin URLs, or the blob: and data: schemes.*".

Comment: The download attribute specifies that the target will be downloaded when a user clicks on the hyperlink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`download` property used to:

1. Inform anchor element to download link instead on open it.
2. While downloading, it will use property value as file name.

In [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_anchor_download) from **w3schools**; open it and click on image, after that remove download property and click it again to see difference.